# jQuery.ajax success callback function not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have a JavaScript Ajax call (jQuery.ajax), that does not execute the success callback function.

```
$.ajax({
        url: target,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        // type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Callback done!");
            // grid.dataBind(result.results);
            // grid.dataBind(result);
        }
    });
```

I see in firebug, that the request is posted and the correct result in terms of the json is returned as expected. What is wrong?

Comment: One problem I've seen that can cause that scenario are if the hosted page and the ajax target are on different domains.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368375/why-does-jquery-ajax-call-only-work-when-im-debugging-in-chrome

 this works try it it worked for me

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For many times I have encountered similar problems and most of the time the reason was a malformed json. Try getting the result as text data type to see whether this is your problem.

Also, I'd like to ask if you're using a parameter like "&jsoncallback=?" in your url, since your data type is jsonp instead of simple json.

Comment: I had same type of problems and mostly it is malformed json. Validate your JSON response at jsonlint.com

Comment: I validated, that it is valid JSON.

Answer (score 6):

Your `$.ajax` call with `dataType: 'jsonp'` could work in these scenarios:

1. You are calling a url on the same domain of your page.
2. You are calling a url out of your domain of your page that supports  [callback](http://shaneosullivan.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/specifying-the-callback-function-with-the-flickr-json-apis/)

If you are out of these two cases, you can't do anything since you can’t make cross site XmlHttpRequest calls.

Comment: Actually, you can; at least in modern browsers. I don't think $.ajax handles that, though.

Comment: Anyway, if it would be a cross-site request, the AJAX call wouldn't return in the first place.

Comment: @Tgr are you sure?Jquery Ajax cross domain call switches to Jsonp, substitutes callback function name to ? on you callback url parameter and calls the url adding a <script> tag in your page header.

Comment: Adding a script tag to your header is not an AJAX call. (I didn't know jQuery can do that, though - cool.) You can do actual cross-domain AJAX calls in modern browsers. It will depend on the target server authorizing you through a special HTTP header, which they usually don't, so it has little practical application as of yet.

Comment: I'm talking about Jquery's Ajax call as OP has requested.

Comment: In my scenario it is the same domain.

Comment: "Adding a script tag to your header is not an AJAX call. (I didn't know jQuery can do that, though - cool.)"
The script is executed, if a button is pressed. The AJAX call is executed, I see the result in firebug.

Comment: @Frank Why are you using dataType: 'jsonp'?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I suspect people still hit this.

I fought this for some time, and eventually gave up and moved to the deferred model.  (I've been using jQuery long enough that I was in the "old" way habits still...)  As soon as I moved to a deferred model, things started to work.  I have no idea why the old way didn't work, but no longer care.  (This question pre-dates the new model.)

cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14754681/199172

Answer (score 1):

You need to set async property to false.

```
$.ajax({
    url: target,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST', // or 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Callback done!");
        // grid.dataBind(result.results);
        // grid.dataBind(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the case for me. This will happen if the page posts back before the AJAX call is finished. The call will generally fail quickly so I was only seeing the error message before my page did a post back.

Comment: if you use a service worker, fast responses can make this happen with much more frequency. The deferred model avoids this. see @MikeBaz 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to one of my co-workers, so I figure I'd add my solution as well.

We could see the ajax call being made, and could see the proper response coming back in Fiddler (status 200 / completely valid JSON), but it would never hit the error, success, or complete callbacks. Adding async: false to the ajax call would make it work, but that wasn't really a proper solution. Additionally placing an alert directly after the ajax call (without the async: false), and waiting a few seconds once the alert was shown, would somehow force the ajax callbacks to work . Very odd indeed...

Turns out, the function with the ajax call was bound to an input of type="submit", which was the source of this odd behavior. Changing the input to type="button" corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

13 years later, jquery still here !.

Anyone who encountered this. Make sure you have '200 OK'  HTTP status as your ajax response. Otherwise jquery will not assume it as success !

Make sure your server script doesn't do redirect somewhere between your request & response process. Ex: middleware, other involved functions, router rules, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This won't apply to newer versions of jQuery, but in my case I am maintaining an older product which utilizes jQuery v3.2.1. I was trying to use an **async callback**, which is not supported in earlier versions. No error or anything, the callback is just not executed.

A workaround is to use `setTimeout`:

```
success: function (data) {
  setTimeout(async function() {
    await someAsyncOperation(data);
  }, 0);
}
```

Related: [jQuery Ajax async function don't fired on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890306/jquery-ajax-async-function-dont-fired-on-success)

Answer (score -1):

Jquery Ajax call to a servlet with mutliple parameters was not calling success  or error even though the call was succesfull. It was bound to a submit button. Changing it returned a success event.

Here is my reference code in case someone needs it for reference.

```
$(document).ready( function () {    
    $("#buttonSave").click(function() {
        alert('incustsave');
        var name = $("#custname").val();
        var gstnumber = $("#gstnumber").val();
        var custbizname = $("#custbizname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var address = $("#address").val();
        var street = $("#street").val();
        var city = $("#city").val();
        var zip = $("#zip").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var country = $("#ctry").val();

        var inputArray = [name, gstnumber, custbizname, email, address, street, city, zip, phone, country];
        var Success = false;
        alert('added_button_and_dt');
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",
            url: "RegisterCustomerServlet",               
            data: {'input': inputArray},
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
                alert('sucess');
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML with Bootstrap3 (Button  reference)

```
<!-- Button -->
<div class='wrapper text-center'>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button"  id="buttonSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Servlet Reference

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HashMap<String,String>  map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    CustomerDAO custinfo = new CustomerDAO();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    CustomerVO vo = new CustomerVO();

    String[] myJsonData = request.getParameterValues("input[]");
    logger.info("in custregisterjsoninput" + myJsonData[0] + myJsonData[2] + myJsonData[3] + myJsonData[4]);

    map.put("custname", myJsonData[0]);
    map.put("getsnumber", myJsonData[1]);
    map.put("custbizname", myJsonData[2]);

    map.put("email", myJsonData[3]);
    map.put("address", myJsonData[4]);
    map.put("street", myJsonData[5]);
    map.put("city", myJsonData[6]);          
    map.put("pincode", myJsonData[7]);
    map.put("mainphone", myJsonData[8]);
    map.put("country", myJsonData[9]);

    try {
        vo = custinfo.saveCustomerInfo(map);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("aftercall"+e.getMessage());
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }  
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(Utility.convertPOJOtoJason(vo));
}
```