# How to post form data to a new window using jQuery/AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

One of the pages in my application has a set of links that when clicked, posts form data based on the TableTools jQuery plugin.  I'd like this new page to open up in a new window.  Any ideas on the best way to do this?  I'd rather not change all of my action links over to individual forms and use `target="_blank"`.  I've tried calling a new window to open on success, and posting writing the data to this page, but that hasn't been working.  Please help!

HTML:

```
<div id="action">                        
    Download
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#action').click( function () { 

    var userData = oTable.fnGetColumnData(0);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../download.php",
        data: "user_list=" + userData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            var win = window.open();
            win.document.write(data);
        }
    })  

})
```

Comment: In your ajax call, where is 'item' defined?

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake in my post.  fixed!

Comment: just use `data: $('form').serializeArray()` if you don't need to customize your data and this works like a charm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer:

[jQuery.ajax success callback function not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787180/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-not-executed)

When I took out the `dataType: "json"`, it worked!