# how can i interact with the external file system using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am using this j query code

```
var = "here is path of file"
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#readFile").click(function () {
        $.get(var, function (data) {
                window.open($("#container").html(data);)
            }, 'text');
    });
});
```

how to open a file that is located in different directory and i want to display the contents in new window with HTML enable tags all things should be written in j query?

Comment: Your best bet is to build a web service that provides access to the file. There is a new Javascript API that could also work, but browser support is currently quite limited.

Comment: `var` is a keyword so `var = "here is path of file"` should cause you problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood correctly you can use Ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#readFile").click(function () {

    var target = '/path/file.html';

    $.ajax({
        url: target,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            var win = window.open();
            win.document.write(data);
        }
    });

    });
});
```

Have a look at this answer: [How to post form data to a new window using jQuery/AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8919019/1838483)

Comment: thanks. i got my answer