# jquery ajax success callback not triggered when rails controller returns 200 OK

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am doing a standard ajax request and I have a rails controller action that does:

```
def up_vote
  resource.votes.increment!
  render :nothing => true
end
```

This does not trigger my jquery ajax success callback---  It does however trigger the statusCode: 200 callback, but I want to use success instead of that.  The rail rendering docs say to use "head" instead of render :nothing => true, so I tried doing head :ok, but that results in the same outcome.

How can I make this method trigger the success callback?

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript as well?

Comment: I am just using a $.ajax with success: function(response) { ... } .. it is not triggered unless I render an actual view.  However, statusCode:200 is always triggered (unless there's an error).  I am just wondering what header jQuery looks for to consider something "successful" so that I can do that in the controller action with head :whatever_jquery_wants

Answer (score 8):

I've just run into the same problem while using the `head :ok` style response with Rails 3.2. I fixed it by changing `dataType: "json"` to `dataType: "text"` within my `$.ajax` call.

It seems like jQuery does not call the success callback if you specify wanting a JSON response, but the returned data does not validate as JSON.

This question gave me the hint I needed to figure it out: [jQuery.ajax success callback function not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787180/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-not-executed)

Answer (score 5):

I've fixed this error by rendering a json response.`render :json => { :success => "success", :status_code => "200" }`

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but it is high in the search engine, so to give it an answer :)

You can do it like this:

```
def up_vote
  resource.votes.increment!
  render :nothing => true

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json  { render json: {} , status: 200 }
  end
end
```