# How to utilize the ResponseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

*Preface*: Forgive me, because I'm quite new when it comes to handling JSON.

I am currently using Rails with jQuery to retrieve some data via JSON.  I am able to successfully grab the data from my controller, but I can't seem to do anything with it.

## *index.html.erb*

```
<a href="#" id="click">Click Me</a>
```

## *clothing.js.erb*

```
$( "#click" ).on( "click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/clothing/get_color",
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
   })
});
```

## *clothing_controller.rb*

```
 def get_color
    #Query goes here

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render :json => @color, status: :ok }
    end
 end
```

When I click on the `$("#click")` link, looking at my Firebug Console, it successfully queries the controller fine, without any errors, and shows the `response` as `blue`.

However, I cannot do anything with this response, such as `alert(response)` or `$("#my_input").val(response)`.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What does your response look like? Is it a string or object?

Comment: have you tried defining the `error: function()` and see if that reutrns anything?

Comment: try console.log(response) to see how response look like

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I added the "error" function, and that seems to be firing.  But when I do `console.log(repsonse)` (within the error function) it shows status "OK" and status (200).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.  Turns out it was triggering the "Error" after the JSON request, instead of success, even though it was responding with a status of `200`.

So, I found this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376924/jquery-ajax-success-callback-not-triggered-when-rails-controller-returns-200-ok), explaining to add `:success=> "success"`.  So, I changed my controller code to:

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.json { render :json => { :success => "success", :status_code => "200", :color => @color } }
end
```

And that worked!

Answer (score 0):

you may need to do JSON.stringify() of the response before you try to output it.

Check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify