# Why does jQuery ajax call only work when I'm debugging in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax call from a form submit.
It works when I debug, i.e the alert pops up but when running it, it doesn't work?

This seems a bit mysterious to me.

```
$(function(){

    $("#signUpForm").submit(function(){
        var request = $.ajax({
            url:"php/newUser.php",
            type:"POST"

        });

        request.done(function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        });


    });
});
```

Comment: you are not sending any data within that `$.ajax` request

Comment: @Victor while you're correct for this case, there is no reason why an AJAX request couldn't/shouldn't be made without a data set

Comment: it was just a sidenote. because as that filename looks like `newUser.php`, it should pass some data to it :))

Comment: newUser.php is just echo 'hi'; I'm just playing around with ajax and it's odd because stepping through the code the alert msg box jumps up but not when I actually run it without debugging.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you run an ajax call on the [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler of a form, the Ajax request will fire but then the form will continue submitting, thus refreshing the page and never firing your callback function.

Instead, you should call `event.preventDefault()` at the end of the submit handler function to prevent the browser from submitting the form normally with a new HTTP request. To do this you'll need to add `event` as a parameter to the callback function, like this:

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

The reason it works when you debug is because everything happens slowly as you step through, without the browser submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Check in case if you have wrote console.log by chance in your method