# check json every second and refresh page when data changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to refresh the whole page when javascript detects a change in json data.

**Here is the code i am trying:**

```js
var previous = null;
    var current = null;
    setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://www.mylivepolls.com/json.php?shortURL=0", function(json){
            current = JSON.stringify(json);
            if(previous && current && previous !== current){
                console.log('refresh');
                location.reload();
            }
            previous = current;
        });
    }, 1000);
```

When this code is executed, it does not refresh the page.

But when i try to open inspect element on that page, it refreshes!

please check if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: use `!=` instead of `!==` ..

Comment: probably since getJSON is an asynchronous function, we cant actually expect the result to be immidiate. and are you sure the page is not refreshed while not in debugging mode?

Comment: @PrashanthBenny yes it only refreshes when i open inspect element :(

Comment: @atulquest93 tried but problem is same as it only refreshes when i open inspect element.

Comment: Did you try with a longer delay? What happens if you put 2000 or 3000 as timer interval?

Comment: try having an alert before and after the location.reload() we could narow down a lot...!

Comment: @Paolo tried longer delay too, same with it, have to open inspect element to run it.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny tried, alerts only come when i open inspect element.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny this is the URL: https://www.mylivepolls.com/templates/1/index2.php?shortURL=0

Comment: i am seriously out of idea.....

have you tried getJSON() .success() and .fail() ?

Comment: @Paolo this is the URL: https://www.mylivepolls.com/templates/1/index2.php?shortURL=0

Comment: var previous = null;
    var current = null;
    setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://www.mylivepolls.com/json.php?shortURL=0")
         .done( function(json){
            current = JSON.stringify(json);
            if(previous && current && previous !== current){
                console.log('refresh');
                location.reload();
            }
            previous = current;
        })
 .fail(function(){
 //do something
 })
    }, 1000);

Comment: @PrashanthBenny haha this is weird that it only works when i open inspect element, anyway till then i will be using simple meta refresh :P

Comment: haha... :D  are you doing something like this [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368375/why-does-jquery-ajax-call-only-work-when-im-debugging-in-chrome) ?

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: @PrashanthBenny no i am still using meta refresh..

Comment: have you tried the .done() and .fail() methods?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly when your debugger has focus, 'location' is being scoped to the frame of the debugger. Try window.location.reload(), instead of simply location.reload().

Comment: oops! same problem with change.