# Get specific part of external webpage through ajax which has http auth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to load the content(specific part) of external webpage through `ajax` request on my webpage.
The `curl` url for the request is as follow

> http://useraname:password@X.X.X.X:PORT

So, I tried the following ajax call to get the webpage

```
var username,password;
$.ajax
  ({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://X.X.X.X:PORT/",
    dataType: 'text/html',
    async: false,
crossDomain: true,
    data: '{"username": "username", "password" : "secret"}',
    success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
    },
error: function (err){
alert(err);
},
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
}
});
```

This gives me a `CORS` error (`Cross-Origin Request Blocked:`). After changing `dataType` from `text/html` to `jsonp`. The I received the response with the following error

> [Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js :: .send :: line 5"  data: no]

The success part of the ajax call is not getting executed in either case. Only it goes to error part. If I received the page than I can fetch the specific part by the following method.

```
  var data = $.parseHTML(res);  //<----try with $.parseHTML().
  $(data).find('div.content').each(function(){
      $('#here').append($(this).html());
```

How to get the required result?

After suggestion of @GuRu, I tried the following, but still the success method is not getting called.

```
var username,password;
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://X.X.X.X:PORT/",
  data: '{"username": "user", "password" : "secret"}',
  async:true, 
  dataType : 'jsonp',  
  crossDomain:true,
    success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
    },
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
  }
  });
```

Comment: try "Content-Type" header to `"text/javascript"` instead of `text/html`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I tried "text/javascript" in `dataType` but still the same error.

Comment: Have you tried with `application/javascript`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Yes that also give the same exception  of `data:no`

Comment: what error you are getting now.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi The error listed above
`[Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js :: .send :: line 5" data: no]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98767/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-ajeet-khan).

Comment: use `async: true`. "Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation."

Comment: @ParthTrivedi now that error is gone but the `status text` is `error` and the request enters in the `error` function rather than in `success`

Answer (score 2):

For JSON text:

> The MIME media type for JSON text is **`application/json`**. The default encoding is UTF-8. (Source: [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)).

For [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) with callback:

> **`application/javascript`**

Here are some blog posts that were mentioned in the comments that are relevant.

- [Why you shouldn't use `text/html` for JSON](http://jibbering.com/blog/?p=514)
- [Internet Explorer sometimes has issues with `application/json`](http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2008/06/06/problems-with-internet-explorer-and-applicationjson/)
- [A rather complete list of Mimetypes and what to use them for](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/mime.types)

Please check [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I thing that help you.

```
var username,password;
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://X.X.X.X:PORT/",
  data: '{"username": "username", "password" : "secret"}',
  async:true, 
  dataType : 'jsonp', //you may use jsonp for cross origin request 
  crossDomain:true,
  success: function (){
      alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
  },
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
  }
});
```

This is work for me, try it using XMLHttpRequest.
The XMLHttpRequest object is used to exchange data with a server.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "user=123&&password=456";
request.open('POST', 'https://www.example.com/controllers/Authentication.php', true);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {if (request.readyState==4) alert("It worked!");};
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
request.send(params);
```

Comment: This is causing error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource`

Comment: please add this on ajax

        `async:true,`
        `dataType : 'jsonp',   //you may use jsonp for cross origin request`
        `crossDomain:true,`

Comment: I did that, the statusText is success but the `done` function is not getting called. Somewhere it is getting error.

Comment: remove done function and put success function in Ajax

Comment: I tried success function as well but still the `success` function is not getting called. see my last edit in the question what I tried.

Comment: @Ajeet Khan please, see the link for the cross domain Ajax as like you http://icant.co.uk/articles/crossdomain-ajax-with-jquery/error-handling.html , I wish you get better solution

Comment: i have tried almost everything, but still can't get the right things to work for me. BTW thankyou for your answers and help. :)

Comment: @Ajeet Khan you can not getting success function because, I think your response is not formatted as per JSON.
see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787180/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-not-executed

Comment: The response is going to be a html page

Comment: I am try using XMLHttpRequest and its work, please see my answer