# jQuery Ajax async function don't fired on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have code like this:

```
jQuery("#test_btn").off("click").on("click", function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/api/test/",
                        data: {
                            test: "me"
                        },
                        success: async function (response) {
                            alert("foo");
                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                            console.error(e);

                        }
                    });
        });
```

why the success function won't print an allert with "foo"? I nedd to use a promise function inside success... but nothing !

Comment: Any chance it logs an error?

Comment: `await async function (response)` - What is the intention behind this construct (which doesn't make any sense)?

Comment: The same question for `.on("click", async function () { ...`

Comment: You don't need async await in this case. Success always fire when success no matter what. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @ThanhTrung I need call an async function inside success function....

Comment: @LiadYogev no log simply don't fire

Comment: @Andreas I have update the code... I had make await async as try to make work... 
now with code like this? no foo print

Comment: You can create the async function inside the success callback

Comment: `success: async function (response)` is still useless as it does not do/change anything

Comment: I need the same thing, to call await in the success function, but when you add "async" in front of it, nothing fires. Very bizarre behavior. There are definitely use cases for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are using an old JQuery version.

In **3.2.1** if you use an async function as feedback doesn't work

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  banner.addClass("alt");
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/test/",
    data: {
      test: "me"
    },
    success: async function(response) {
      alert("Success!");
    },
    error: async function(e) {
      alert('O no, an error! :(');
      console.error(e);

    }
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="banner-message">
  <button>Send XHR request</button>
</div>
```

In **3.3.1 and above work perfectly**

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  banner.addClass("alt");
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/test/",
    data: {
      test: "me"
    },
    success: async function(response) {
      alert("Success!");
    },
    error: async function(e) {
      alert('O no, an error! :(');
      console.error(e);

    }
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <button>Send XHR request</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery don't support async on callback need to use fetch api like this

```
await fetch("/api/test/", {
                        method: "post",
                        body:
                            'nonce=' + encodeURIComponent("<?= generate_nonce(); ?>") +
                            "&user_id=" + encodeURIComponent("<?= $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>") +
                            "&supername=" + encodeURIComponent("<?= $_REQUEST['bot_name']; ?>") +
                            "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(valore_base) +
                            "&simple=" + encodeURIComponent("check"),
                        headers:
                            {
                                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                            }

                    })
                        .then(async function (response) {
//success here 
});
```

another solution thanks to @Kalimah Apps
is declare an async function inside success callback....
the basis is that **the jQuery callback can't be async**

```
jQuery("#test_btn").off("click").on("click", function () {
jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/test/",
                data: {
                    test: "me"
                },
                success: function (response) {

                    async function abc(response){
                        await my_sync_func(response);
                        alert("done after async")
                    }
                    abc(response);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.error(e);

                }
});
```

});

Comment: `async` in `.then(async function (response)` is not necessary as `.then()` will always return a `Promise`. `async function abc(response) { ... }` abc(response);` doesn't make sense either.

Comment: `await`ing a synchronous function (`await my_sync_func`) makes no sense.

Comment: I still don't understand the need of the OP here. Why the need of async await. To do what after?

Comment: @Andreas I found the real problem.... bug of version 3.2.1 oj jquery :(
I'll post a new answer with two fiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX(Asynchronous Javascript and XML) by its name it is clearly understood that the AJAX request is always asynchronous.

If you want it to be synchronous just add this,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false //by default it will be true
});
```

In addition to that,

> The jQuery post() method sends an asynchronous http POST request to the
>   server to submit the data to the server and get the response.

```
$.post('/jquery/submitData',   // url
   { myData: 'This is my data.' }, // data to be submit
   function(data, status, jqXHR) {
     // success callback
    })
```

Syntax:

```
$.post(url,[data],[callback],[type]);
```

Please refer [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-post-method) API documentation for further information. This would be helpful.

Comment: `async: false` is almost never (as in this case) the right way

Comment: Yes, you are correct. @Andreas I have mentioned it because to highlight that we can also make it as synchronous by including that line.

Answer (score 0):

As the JairSnow's way, my app are using jQuery 2.2.4. And I must have following code to use jQuery 3.4.1 parallel with jQuery 2.2.4 (and I am using ASP.NET MVC):

In the index.cshtml, I added following code:

```html
<!-- load jQuery 3.4.1 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery3.4.1/jquery.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery_3_4_1 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>
```

In javascript, I added following code:

```js
jQuery_3_4_1.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Product/GetById',
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "json",
            success: async function (item) {
                // ... my code...
                let productData;
                productData = await getFactor();
                // ... my code...
            },
            error: function (err) {
                general.notify('Error', 'error');
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

And it run successfully.
You can refer way to use multiple jQuery version here: [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)